# Using iframe tag with php

Tags: php, iframe

I´m trying to read a .pdf file with an iframe in PHP, with this code:

```
...
<?php
if(isset($_POST['r']))
{
    //echo $_POST['r'];?>
    <p align="center"><iframe src="<?php echo $_POST['r'];?>" style="width:800px; height:600px;" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
    </p>-->

...


    <?php
}
```

$_POST['r'] is the file URL

But when I open the php file of my website i can see the page that the iframe loaded, but it just shows up as a blank page, not the iframe with the document. When i look in the inspector (console), it show me this:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxxxxx/example.php'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource
>   'http://www.xxxxxxx.es/'. This request has been blocked; the content
>   must be served over HTTPS.

I have reviewed all the code and can not find any reference to http, so i am not sure why it shows the blank page and show that error.

Comment: "I have reviewed all the code and can not find any reference to http" — It certainly doesn't appear in the code you've shared with us. We can't reproduce the problem with the information you've supplied.

Comment: Likely relevant: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/prevent-mixed-content/fixing-mixed-content

Comment: Any image or other resource loaded with HTTP will prevent the page to use HTTPS, you must be sure all stuff you load in the iframe is HTTPS provided

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed there was a very hidden reference to an http url that was the one that was giving me problems.

Answer (score 1):

Start by checking if the page you are trying to load allows loading using iFrames:
https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/07/20/block-iframe-loading/

Comment: Solved. There was a very hidden reference to an http url. Very instructive the page. Every day you learn something more in this forum. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Please consider updating your subject with your solution if you can.